# List files installed by a package on my Linux system (Ubuntu / APT)

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management

When I install a new package in Ubuntu (using APT), like this:

`sudo apt install binutils`

it will install me the **/usr/bin/nm** utility. But it will also install other files in other locations.

Is there a way to see what files were installed by a specific package and in what locations? (Maybe see the list of files that will be installed before actually installing the package!)

I know that the reverse operation (see the belonging package for a file) can be achieved with the **apt-file** command.

Comment: You can also use apt-file (specifically, `apt-file list`) for the forward operation - from `man apt-file` *This action is very close to the `dpkg -L` command except the package does not need to be installed or fetched.*

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer myself:

```
dpkg -L <package-name>
```

eg:

```
liviu@core-i5:~$dpkg -L binutils
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/compat-ld
/usr/lib/gold-ld
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/share
/usr/share/bug
/usr/share/bug/binutils
/usr/share/bug/binutils/presubj
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/binutils
/usr/share/doc/binutils/copyright
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/binutils
/usr/share/man
/usr/bin/addr2line
/usr/bin/ar
/usr/bin/as
/usr/bin/c++filt
/usr/bin/dwp
/usr/bin/elfedit
/usr/bin/gold
/usr/bin/gprof
/usr/bin/ld
/usr/bin/ld.bfd
/usr/bin/ld.gold
/usr/bin/nm
/usr/bin/objcopy
/usr/bin/objdump
/usr/bin/ranlib
/usr/bin/readelf
/usr/bin/size
/usr/bin/strings
/usr/bin/strip
/usr/lib/compat-ld/ld
/usr/lib/gold-ld/ld
/usr/share/doc/binutils/changelog.Debian.gz
```